# How to insert a hyphen in Microsoft Equations instead of a minus sign?

Tags: equation-editor

When you write `a-b` in a Microsoft equation it assumes that this is 'a minus b' and adds spacing around the minus sign accordingly.  But what if you want a hyphen instead such as in a double-barrelled name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply adding speech marks around the text causes it to be treated as 'Normal text' so the minus sign is treated as a hyphen with no spacing around it.

Regular minus sign by typing `a-b`:

[image]

Hyphen by typing `"a-b"`:

[image]

Comment: This works, but I get the resulting string in non-italics, as opposed to everything else in the equation editor.

Comment: I got it - the way to do it is to add _only_ the hyphen in double quotes: `a"-"b` will yield the expected result with both `a` and `b` in italics. Note that if you 'cut and paste `a"-"b` into an equation you need to position the cursor right after the second double quote and before the `b` and then press space - that will apply the 'Normal text' to the hyphen and remove the double quotes.